# Get Distance Between Specific Point to the Line Drawn on Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I have a point (lat, lng) X and a route drawn on the google map as shown below.

[image]

In my app, I have a rule:

> If the distance between point X to the nearest point that is passed by
>   the route is **less than 5 meters**, then the **route can be traversed**.
>
> Otherwise, if the distance between points X to the closest point
>   passed by the route is **equal to or greater than 5 meters**, then the
>   route **cannot be traversed**.

Is this rule can be applied by using google map service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Maps Javascript API has a [Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry).

The Geometry library has a `isLocationOnEdge` function. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge).

> To determine whether a point falls on or near a polyline, or on or near the edge of a polygon, pass the point, the polyline/polygon, and optionally a tolerance value in degrees to `google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge()`. The function returns true if the distance between the point and the closest point on the line or edge falls within the specified tolerance. The default tolerance value is 10<sup>-9</sup> degrees.